# How to autowire @ConfigurationProperties into @Configuration?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, autowired

I have a properties class defined like this:

```
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "plugin.httpclient")
public class HttpClientProperties {
   ...
}
```

And a configuration class like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class HttpClientConfiguration {

    private final HttpClientProperties httpClientProperties;

    @Autowired
    public HttpClientConfiguration(HttpClientProperties httpClientProperties) {
        this.httpClientProperties = httpClientProperties;
    }

    ...
}
```

When starting my spring boot application, I'm getting

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in x.y.z.config.HttpClientConfiguration required a bean of type 'x.y.z.config.HttpClientProperties' that could not be found.
```

Is this not a valid use case, or do I have to declare the dependencies some how?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a valid use case, however, your `HttpClientProperties` are not picked up because they're not scanned by the component scanner. You could annotate your `HttpClientProperties` with `@Component`:

```
@Validated
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "plugin.httpclient")
public class HttpClientProperties {
    // ...
}
```

Another way of doing so (as mentioned by [Stephane Nicoll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43797924/how-to-autowire-configurationproperties-into-configuration/43798111?noredirect=1#comment74645778_43798111)) is by using the `@EnableConfigurationProperties()` annotation on a Spring configuration class, for example:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(HttpClientProperties.class) // This is the recommended way
@EnableScheduling
public class HttpClientConfiguration {
    // ...
}
```

This is also described in the [Spring boot docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties).

Comment: There is still one thing that bothers me though. I have another ConfigurationProperties class that is also not annotated as a Component, but that is autowired into a Component. That works. How come?

Comment: @Daniel there must be another difference then. Either the bean is created inside a configuration class (annotated with `@Bean`) or there is another annotation on the configuration properties class that allows component scanning.

Comment: Actually we don't really recommend to use `@Component` and this is described in the doc already: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties

Comment: Realized my issue after reading up on Stephane's, link. My first configuration class (which I created a long time ago) is included with @EnableConfigurationProperties(PluginProperties.class) in my main class. I just have to add the HttpClientProperties.class in there as well

Comment: @StephaneNicoll Unless I'm seriously misreading, the link you provided does encourage using `@Component` along with `@ConfigurationProperties`. See the sentence that begins "_You could shortcut MyConfiguration by making sure AcmeProperties is already a bean, as shown in the following example_".

Or if not strictly _encouraging_, it's certainly not _discouraging_ this practice.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, this is a link to `current` so the wording may have changed. The important bits are "Even if the preceding configuration creates a regular bean for AcmeProperties, we recommend that @ConfigurationProperties only deal with the environment and, in particular, does not inject other beans from the context.". By not using `@Component` you make it a bit clearer that this object is special and is not supposed to inject other dependencies. That's what `@EnableConfigurationProperties(ABC.class)` gives you.

Comment: you can use `@Configuration` on your `HttpClientProperties` file instead of `@Component`

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Boot 2.2.1+, add the `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` annotation to the application. (Note that this was enabled by default in version 2.2.0.) This will allow all classes annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` to be picked up without using `@EnableConfigurationProperties` or `@Component`.

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

---

Also, to generate metadata for the classes annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`, which is used by IDEs to provide autocompletion and documentation in application.properties, remember to add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```