# How is @ConfigurationProperties-annotated classes detected automatically with @SpringBootApplication Annotation

Tags: spring-boot, component-scan

I am learning Spring Boot and have a question with one example in the reference documentation. 
Following section of the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation) mentions

**6. Using the @SpringBootApplication Annotation**

> A single @SpringBootApplication annotation can be used to enable those
>   three features, that is:
>
> @EnableAutoConfiguration: enable Spring Boot’s auto-configuration
>   mechanism
>
> @ComponentScan: enable @Component scan on the package where the
>   application is located (see the best practices)
>
> @Configuration: allow to register extra beans in the context or import
>   additional configuration classes

and the following example to ***replace this single annotation by any of the features that it enables*** is bit confusing for me . The example

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import({ MyConfig.class, MyAnotherConfig.class })
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Explanation for the example

> In this example, Application is just like any other Spring Boot
>   application except that @Component-annotated classes and
>   **@ConfigurationProperties-annotated classes are not detected**
>   **automatically** and the user-defined beans are imported explicitly (see
>   @Import).

The only major difference I see in the example code above is that it does not have `@ComponentScan` annotation. I also read in the comments section of an SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43798111/4214241) (Stephane Nicoll May 5 '17 at 11:07) that @Component annotation is not recommended officially to auto detect @ConfigurationProperties. So my assumption is that Spring framework classes with @ConfigurationProperties are not annotated with @Component.

Also I checked the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation source and couldn't identify anything that should enable the automatic detection of `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated classes.

The reference document [2.8.3. Enabling @ConfigurationProperties-annotated types](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-enabling) section shows the following way to scan and autodetect @ConfigurationProperties

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan({ "com.example.app", "org.acme.another" })
public class MyApplication {
}
```

With all these details , I would like to understand

Why is it explicitly mentioned for this example that *@ConfigurationProperties-annotated classes are not detected automatically* ? and How is @ConfigurationProperties annotated classes automatically detected when @SpringBootApplication is used.

Additional note : I saw a small difference between the [prior version](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) of the documentation and the [current](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) one. The following reference is missing the current one

> Keep in mind that the @EnableConfigurationProperties annotation is
>   also automatically applied to your project so that any existing bean
>   annotated with @ConfigurationProperties is configured from the
>   Environment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following is what I understand from my analysis.

`@ConfigurationProperties` annotated types can be registered to the  ApplicationContext by

1. Annotating the class with `@ConfigurationProperties` with an
   annotation that falls in the scope of `@ComponentScan` (
   `@Component`, `@Service` and the like ) . Not recommended as per the comment from Stephane Nicoll , which makes sense to me now.
2. Using annotation
       `@EnableConfigurationProperties` . For this to
       work the class annotated with `@EnableConfigurationProperties`
       should be annotated with an annotation that falls in the scope of
       `@ComponentScan` ( `@Component`, `@Service` and the like )
3. Using annotation `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` and by making sure
       the classes annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` is placed
       under its radar. The usage is similar to `@ComponentScan` .

Now , when we replace `@SpringBootApplication` with individual annotations that it enables and omit `@ComponentScan` (as in example) , the `@EnableConfigurationProperties` way (Point 2) of registering the types with `@ConfigurationProperties` will not work. This probably answers both my questions on why and how .

This was explicitly mentioned probably because the connection between `@EnableConfigurationProperties` and `@ComponentScan` is not that obvious for people like me.

**Additional details.**

The registration of `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated types when we use `@EnableConfigurationProperties` happens through of the `EnableConfigurationPropertiesRegistrar` class that is imported by the annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Import(EnableConfigurationPropertiesRegistrar.class)
public @interface EnableConfigurationProperties {..}
```