# Spring ConfigurationProperties Issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

I have a spring boot application & this piece of code as below

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = “asynchronous-helper”)
public class AsynchronousHelper {
   private transient ExecutorService executor;
}
```

In properties file I have

```
asynchronous-helper.executor.maximumPoolSize=10
asynchronous-helper.executor.corePoolSize=10
```

While maximumPoolSize works corePoolSize fails with below error

```
Failed to bind properties under ‘asynchronous-helper.executor’ to java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService:

Property: asynchronous-helper.executor.corepoolsize
Value: 10
Origin: “asynchronous-helper.executor.corePoolSize” from property source “class path resource [backend-product.properties]”
Reason: Failed to bind properties under ‘asynchronous-helper.executor’ to java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService

Action:
Update your application’s configuration
```

Concrete class of the executor is java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor

Any idea why this happens & how to resolve it?

Comment: spring boot version ?

Comment: will [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59691341/4214241) help ?

Comment: spring-boot version 2.1.1.RELEASE

Comment: Try annotating the class `AsynchronousHelper ` with `@Component` or `@Configuration` so that it will be auto detected during component scan .

Comment: What is the concrete type of your `executor` and how have you created an instance of it?

Comment: R.G - There is no issue in detecting. Like I have mentioned maximumPoolSize works only corePoolSize fails.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Concrete class of the executor is java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor. Added details in the question.

Comment: How do you know maximumPoolSize is working?  Not saying that it is not, but just want to know how exactly you proved that it is working.

Comment: @JoseMartinez Our framework provides a Bean navigator implementation to read & set all properties of any bean. It uses reflection. But we want to move to standard way of overriding. That's when I encountered the above issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked. Created a config bean

```
@Configuration
public class AsyncHelperConfig {
  @Value("${asynchronous-helper.executor.core-pool-size:10}")
  private Integer corePoolSize;

  @Value("${asynchronous-helper.executor.maximum-pool-size:10}")
  private Integer maximumPoolSize;

  @Value("${asynchronous-helper.executor.keep-alive-time:10}")
  private Integer keepAliveTime;

  private transient ExecutorService executor;

@Bean
public AsynchronousHelper asynchronousHelper(){
    AsynchronousHelper asynchronousHelper = new AsynchronousHelper();
    executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, 
   keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.MINUTES,
            new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
    asynchronousHelper.setExecutor(executor);
    return asynchronousHelper;
}
```

And in the beans.xml added the below config

```
<bean id="AsyncHelperConfig" 
    class="asynchonous.AsyncHelperConfig"/>
```